# Similar "Handler" class in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Recently learning Android, there is a Handler class in android which is very useful. We can "post" runnable object to the end of another thread, something like queue, it is very dynamic in that case. Anyone know any similar class in Java SE that is able to do that?

Comment: [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to execute a `Runnable` on a background thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JavaSwing` has `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` that takes a Runnable as paramter. That's one way to post something on the UI Thead

Comment: ExectuorService has a post method to submit a task to a pool of thread for instance